# Meaning of verb followed by ちゃ

Tags: grammar, て-form, particle-は, negation, contractions

A mother is scolding her daughter. The uncle (Tomozou) speaks first:

> 「おかあさん、お歳暮の広告見**ちゃ**ダメ？」
> 友蔵が頼んでもおかあさんは首を縦に振らなかった。
> 「ダメですっ。」
>
> "Mother, is looking at year-end adverts not allowed?"
> Even though it was Tomozou who asked, mother didn't nod in agreement.
> "It's not allowed."
> (my TL attempt)

My main question is what is the meaning of ちゃ (in bold).
If I were to say this I would write something like お歳暮の広告を見るのはダメ。So my first thought was that ちゃ could be a contraction of のは but that doesn't sound likely.

My secondary question (possibly related) is why does it say that the mother **didn't** nod in agreement? I guess this is something to do with how you answer negative questions in Japanese, but even then it seems like a strange thing to say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ちゃ is a contraction of ては. 見ちゃダメ？ is the same as 見てはダメ？

Comment: I see. Like てはいけない. Didn';t realise that's how だめ worked.