# Meaning of こう言っちゃ何ですけど

Tags: meaning

I kind of get when it's supposed to be used, but I'd like a clear explanation on what it really means.

> こう言っちゃ何ですけど。

Comment: See @Chocolate's answer in:  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40005/what-does-%e3%81%93%e3%81%93%e3%81%98%e3%82%83%e4%bd%95%e3%81%a0-means-in-this-sentence/40008#40008

Comment: Thanks. What about the こう言っちゃ part? It feels like some sort of ''I'm just saying". I'm trying to comprehend the grammatical construction.

Comment: ちゃ is a colloquial pronunciation of ては. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42196/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32707/9831

Comment: I figured, but I don't understand why it's こう言っては何ですけど and not こう言うなんですけど or 言ってなんですけど. Is there a grammatical explanation?

Comment: @Ushiromiya What is "こう言うなんですけど or 言ってなんですけど" supposed to mean (in English)? Anyway, こう言っては何ですけど means "although it's 何 (euphemism for "insolence") if I say like this".

Comment: ては is conditional. こう言ってはなんですが ="if I say like this it may sound bad, but...". The conditional part is essential.

Comment: Ah, I see! I didn't know that ては could be used as conditional. Thank you everyone.