# What does it mean についちゃ in this text?

Tags: grammar, spoken-language

> こういうのも なんだが魚たちの ゴキゲンについちゃおれら 漁師が 専門家だ。

What does it mean についちゃ ? What grammar does it refer To ?

Comment: Hint:  [Meaning of verb followed by ちゃ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32707/78)

Comment: Related (regarding ちゃ): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32707/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42196/9831